# Laravel (Blade) - Formulario de login con token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo un proyecto con Laravel donde tengo una API, y mediante passport hago el registro y login de los usuarios

**Controlador AuthController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;



class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public $successStatus = 200;


    public function login()
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }


    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
        }
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
        return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus);
    }

  

}
```

Y las rutas para estos metodos són las siguientes

**Fichero routes/api.php**

```
//REGISTER,LOGIN, LOGOUT
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
```

Ahora tengo un formulario con blade para hacer el login

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Esto lo que hace es , si la autenticación es correcta devuelve un "token", y dicho token lo quiero usar para las llamadas API.

Mi pregunta es, como gestiono esto? Es decir hago el formulario blade anterior y me devuelve el token, este token como lo guardo? En la sesión del navegador? Y lo envío en cada petición api?

O puedo gestionarlo mediante un middleware, que si el usuario este loggeado envie en cada petición el token como header?

Comment: Por lo general, la api sirve para web apps progresivas, teniendolo en el mismo lado que laravel, no tendria mucho caso pues podrias usar el facade Auth, si aun asi deseas usarlo, el token debes guardarlo en localStorage y enviar todas tus solicitudes con el header Authentication Bearer [token]

Comment: Este proyecto por una parte tiene las rutas API, que lo uso para aplicaciones de android/ios, alli si que autentico mediante token, pero luego tiene una parte de "frontal" web que lo hago dentro de este mismo proyecto, donde el usuario se autentica mediante el formulario que he puesto anteriormente, una vez autenticado  lo "guai" seria que al middleware de API (por donde pasan las rutas) le pudiese indicar que dicho usario esta autenticado.